# ¿Cómo cambio el color a la letra del botón en Ionic?

Tags: html, ionic, cordova

¿Cómo puedo ponerle color a la letra de mi botón?

Este es mi código:

```html
<div padding>
  <button ion-button color="light" text-color="quest">Ingresar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad ionic o cordova no acepta css?¿

Comment: Acepta scss....

Comment: ¿Y por que no manejas los estilos directamente con scss luego usas un compilador para que lo entienda el browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando tu código y aplicando el `CSS` siguiente (en tu caso sería un `SCCS`) propondría la siguiente solución:

```css
.buttonIngresar{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div padding>
      <button ion-button color="light" class="buttonIngresar">Ingresar</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para modificar colores en Ionic puedes crear tus propias variables de color dentro de src/theme/variables.scss.
Es tan sencillo como ir a la variable:

```css
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

Y con esto tienes la posibilidad de agregar tus propios colores, Ej.

```css
$colors: (
  ...
  login-button: #F2F2F2,
  ...
);
```

De esta forma podrás utilizarlo en tu código:

```html
<div padding>
  <button ion-button color="login-button" text-color="quest">Ingresar</button>
</div>
```

Claro que siempre puedes agregarle un class="" al elemento para posteriormente agregar sus estilos personalizados en tus hojas de estilos SCSS.

Saludos!